# Image capture and saving issues for phones with no SD card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

My android application captures image and stores it in external memory in application folder which I have created, but when I run the application on phones with external storage not removable. I mean with phones having no SD card the app captures the image and then force closes. The image cannot be written to external storage with phones without SD card.

This is my main activity

```
package com.kamp.linguist;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kamp.linguist.util.SystemUiHider;
import com.memetix.mst.language.Language;
import com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 * 
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */

      private AutoFocusManager autoFocusManager;
      private tesseract tesseract;
      private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;
      public static final String lang = "eng";
      public static String langsrc;
      public static String binglangsrc;
      public static String langtar;
      public static String srcprefkey="srckey";
      public static String tarprefkey="tarkey";
      public static String langflag=null;
      //private static final String TAG = "SimpleAndroidOCR.java";

      private static String DATA_PATH="";

      private static final String TAG = "CameraActivity";
      private final Context context=null;
      private Camera camera = null;
      public static final String MYPREFS="mysharedprefrences";
      /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
     * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
     */
    private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

    /**
     * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
     */
    private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    /**
     * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
     */
    private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;
    Button srclang ;
    Button targetlang ;
    String recognizedTexttrans="";
    String recognizedText="";


        SharedPreferences mysp; 
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         autoFocusManager = new AutoFocusManager(context, camera);
         mysp= getSharedPreferences(MYPREFS,Activity.MODE_PRIVATE); 
         editor=mysp.edit();
    /*if(Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable())
        {
            EXT_PATH= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Linguist/";
              DATA_PATH= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Linguist/"+langsrc+"/";
               IMAGE = EXT_PATH+"capture.jpg";
        }else{
            EXT_PATH= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Linguist/";
              DATA_PATH= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Linguist/"+langsrc+"/";
               IMAGE = EXT_PATH+"capture.jpg";
        }*/


    /*String[] paths = new String[] { DATA_PATH, DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" };
        for (String path : paths) {
            File dir = new File(path);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path + " on sdcard failed");
                    return;
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Created directory " + path + " on sdcard");
                }
            }

        }*/


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

        // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
        // this activity.
        mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView,
                HIDER_FLAGS);
        mSystemUiHider.setup();
        mSystemUiHider
                .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    // Cached values.
                    int mControlsHeight;
                    int mShortAnimTime;

                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                    public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                            // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                            // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                            // screen.
                            if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                                mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                            }
                            if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                                mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                        android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                            }
                            controlsView
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                    .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                        } else {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                            // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                            // controls.
                            controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE
                                    : View.GONE);
                        }

                        if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                            // Schedule a hide().
                            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                        }
                    }
                });

        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                    //autoFocusManager.start();
                    mSystemUiHider.toggle();
                } else {
                    //autoFocusManager.start();

                    mSystemUiHider.show();
                }
            }
        });
    final View forfocus = findViewById(R.id.forauto);
        forfocus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                 Toast.makeText(FullscreenActivity.this,"Source lang: " + langsrc + "\nTarget lang:" + langtar,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                autoFocusManager.start();
            }
        });

            // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.
        findViewById(R.id.targetlang).setOnTouchListener(
                mDelayHideTouchListener);

          final CameraSurfaceView cameraView =
                    new CameraSurfaceView(getApplicationContext());
                final FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.cam);    
                frame.addView(cameraView);

                Button capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
                capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //autoFocusManager.start();
                         cameraView.capture(new Camera.PictureCallback() {
                                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                                  // Save the image JPEG data to the SD card
                                     File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Linguist");
                                     dir.mkdir();
                                        try {
                                              File file =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Linguist", "capture.jpg") ;
                                              file.mkdir();
                                              if(!file.exists()){
                                                  try {
                                                    file.createNewFile();

                                                  } catch (IOException e) {

                                                      e.printStackTrace();
                                                  }
                                              }else{
                                                  file.delete();
                                                  try {
                                                      file.createNewFile();
                                                  } catch (IOException e) {

                                                      e.printStackTrace();
                                                  }
                                              }
                                              if(file.canWrite()){
                                                  Toast.makeText(FullscreenActivity.this,"writeable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                                              }else{
                                                  Toast.makeText(FullscreenActivity.this,"access denined!!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                                              }

                                              FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
                                              fos.write(data);

                                              fos.close();
                                             Toast.makeText(FullscreenActivity.this,"Successfully created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                              Log.e(TAG, "File Note Found", e);
                                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                              Log.e(TAG, "IO Exception", e);
                                            }

                                    // tess();
                                }
                         });

                    }
                });

                Button tee = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                tee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                     public void onClick(View v) {

                        tess();
                        //trans();
                     }
                });


                Button swap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
                swap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                     public void onClick(View v) {

                         String tempsrclang,templangshow = null;
                            tempsrclang=langtar;
                             if(langsrc.equals("eng")){
                                 langtar="en";
                                 templangshow="English";
                               }else if(langsrc.equals("hin")){
                                   langtar="hi";
                                   templangshow="Hindi";
                               }else if(langsrc.equals("spa")){
                                   langtar="es";
                                   templangshow="Spanish";
                               }else if(langsrc.equals("chi_tra")){
                                   langtar="zh-CHT";
                                   templangshow="Chinese";
                               } else if(langsrc.equals("fra")){
                                 langtar="fr";
                                templangshow="French";
                               } 
                             targetlang.setText(templangshow);
                                editor.putString(tarprefkey,templangshow);



                             if(tempsrclang.equals("en")){
                               langsrc="eng";
                             templangshow="English";
                           }else if(tempsrclang.equals("hi")){
                             langsrc="hin";
                            templangshow="Hindi";
                           }else if(tempsrclang.equals("es")){
                             langsrc="spa";
                            templangshow="Spanish";
                           } else if(tempsrclang.equals("zh-CHT")){
                             langsrc="chi_tra";
                            templangshow="Chinese";
                           } else if(tempsrclang.equals("fr")){
                             langsrc="fra";
                            templangshow="French";
                           }
                             srclang.setText(templangshow);
                            editor.putString(srcprefkey,templangshow);
                             createdir();
                                editor.commit();

                     }

                });



                srclang = (Button) findViewById(R.id.srclang);
                srclang.setText(langsrc);
                 registerForContextMenu(srclang);
                srclang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                     public void onClick(View v) {

                         openContextMenu(v);


                     }


                });


                targetlang = (Button) findViewById(R.id.targetlang);
                targetlang.setText(langtar);
                registerForContextMenu(targetlang);
                targetlang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                     public void onClick(View v) {

                         openContextMenu(v);


                     }


                });

                 restore(); 
                 createdir();

            }   


     private void createdir() {
         //Boolean stor =Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated();
         if(Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable())//stor==true)
            {
             DATA_PATH= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Linguist/"+langsrc+"/";
             String[] paths = new String[] { DATA_PATH, DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" };
                for (String path : paths) {
                    File dir = new File(path);
                    if (!dir.exists()) {
                        if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                            Log.v(TAG, "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path + " on sdcard failed");
                            return;
                        } else {
                            Log.v(TAG, "Created directory " + path + " on sdcard");
                        }
                    }

                }


            }else{

                DATA_PATH= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Linguist/"+langsrc+"/";
                 String[] paths = new String[] { DATA_PATH, DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" };
                    for (String path : paths) {
                        File dir = new File(path);
                        if (!dir.exists()) {
                            if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                                Log.v(TAG, "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path + " on sdcard failed");
                                return;
                            } else {
                                Log.v(TAG, "Created directory " + path + " on sdcard");
                            }
                        }

                    }


            }

    }


    @Override  
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,  
                  ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  

             super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo); 

             MenuInflater m = getMenuInflater();  
            if(v.getId()==R.id.srclang){
                langflag="source";
                m.inflate(R.menu.sourcelang, menu); 
            }
             else if(v.getId()==R.id.targetlang){
                 langflag="target";
             m.inflate(R.menu.targetlang, menu);
             }  
        }  
         @Override  
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 

             String strlong =item.getTitle().toString();

           String strshort = null;


            if(langflag=="source"){

                 if(strlong.equals("English")){
                   strshort="eng";
               }else if(strlong.equals("Hindi")){
                   strshort="hin";
               }else if(strlong.equals("Spanish")){
                   strshort="spa";
               } else if(strlong.equals("Chinese")){
                   strshort="chi_tra";
               } else if(strlong.equals("French")){
                   strshort="fra";
               }
                        srclang.setText(item.getTitle());
                        editor.putString(srcprefkey, strlong);
                        langsrc=strshort;
                        createdir();
                       Toast.makeText(FullscreenActivity.this,"Selected Source Language:"+strlong,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(langflag=="target"){

                 if(strlong.equals("English")){
                       strshort="en";
                   }else if(strlong.equals("Hindi")){
                       strshort="hi";
                   }else if(strlong.equals("Spanish")){
                       strshort="es";
                   }else if(strlong.equals("Chinese")){
                       strshort="zh-CHT";
                   }else if(strlong.equals("French")){
                       strshort="fr";
                   }   

                    targetlang.setText(item.getTitle());
                    editor.putString(tarprefkey, strlong);
                     langtar=strshort;
                     Toast.makeText(FullscreenActivity.this,"Selected Target Language:"+strlong,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            editor.commit();
            //store(str);

             return super.onContextItemSelected(item);  
        }





  private void tess(){
      tesseract=new tesseract();
      recognizedText=tesseract.tess(langsrc);
      if(recognizedText.equals(null)){
          Toast.makeText(FullscreenActivity.this,"OCR Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
         trans();

}




    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSystemUiHider.hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }

     public void restore()
      {

            int mode=Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
            SharedPreferences mysp= getSharedPreferences(MYPREFS, mode);    

            if(mysp.contains(srcprefkey)){
            langsrc=mysp.getString(srcprefkey,"");
            }
            else{
                langsrc="English";
            }
            if(mysp.contains(tarprefkey)){
                langtar=mysp.getString(tarprefkey,"");
                }
                else{
                    langtar="Hindi";
                }

            srclang.setText(langsrc);
            targetlang.setText(langtar);


            convertsrclang(langsrc);
        converttargetlang(langtar);


      }


     private void convertsrclang(String langsrc2) {
         if(langsrc2.equals("English")){
             langsrc="eng";
           }else if(langsrc2.equals("Hindi")){
               langsrc="hin";
           }else if(langsrc2.equals("Spanish")){
               langsrc="spa";
           }else if(langsrc2.equals("Chinese")){
               langsrc="chi_tra";
           }else if(langsrc2.equals("French")){
               langsrc="fra";
           }  

    }


    private void converttargetlang(String langtar2) {
         if(langtar2.equals("English")){
             langtar="en";
           }else if(langtar2.equals("Hindi")){
               langtar="hi";
           }else if(langtar2.equals("Spanish")){
               langtar="es";
           }else if(langtar2.equals("Chinese")){
               langtar="zh-CHT";
           }else if(langtar2.equals("French")){
               langtar="fr";
           }  

    }



     private void trans() {


             new MyAsyncTask() { 
                 protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText( "RecoText: "+ recognizedText+"\n TransText:"+recognizedTexttrans);

                 }
             }.execute();
        } 
         class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
                @Override

                protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                    convertbingsrclang();
                    Translate.setClientId("MicrosoftTranslatorJavaAPI");
                    Translate.setClientSecret("0VHbhXQnJrZ7OwVqcoX/PDZlyLJS9co3cVev1TPr8iM=");
                    try {
                        recognizedTexttrans = Translate.execute(recognizedText,Language.fromString(binglangsrc), Language.fromString(langtar));
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        recognizedTexttrans = e.toString();
                    }
                    return true;
                }


            }
         private void convertbingsrclang() {
             if(langsrc.equals("eng")){
                 binglangsrc="en";
               }else if(langsrc.equals("hin")){
                   binglangsrc="hi";
               }else if(langsrc.equals("spa")){
                   binglangsrc="es";
               }else if(langsrc.equals("chi_tra")){
                   binglangsrc="zh-CHT";
               } else if(langsrc.equals("fra")){
                   binglangsrc="fr";
               } 

            }
  }
```

Comment: Code and the error log, please.

Comment: im new to stack overflow..! how can i put the code..its telling me to add 4 spaces at each line...is it??

Comment: can u give me your mail id..!! will talk there if possible..!

Comment: insert the code into question, select whole code part and press `ctrl+K` so your code will be informatted manner.

Comment: Ok, good, now copy & paste your error log below the question code.

Comment: yeah...!! please suggest me something..im trying to save the image file in external memory....!! But with phones with no SD card the app doesnt store the image....i hope you getting my problem..!! Thanks !

Comment: Actually my AVD isnt working .so im debugging it in phone....USB debugging also unfortunately down! So cant get the error log!

Comment: What do you mean by down ? Developer Option is not there ?

Comment: I guess the problem is basically with the image store in non removable external memory devices..as my application is working fine with other phones with SD cards

Comment: ok instead of this line `File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Linguist");` try this line `File dir = new File("/Linguist");` and see it gives an error or not .

Comment: No error....Its still creating the folder linguist in external memory but doesn't store the image!

Comment: Good, but why you have that `File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Linguist");` statement two time ? did you replace my line at both the places ?

Comment: its not two time..first we create the dir and in second add a capture.jpg filde to it! after u said i did File dir= new File("/Linguist"); and below that for image i did File file= new File(dir.tostring((),"capture"+".jpg"); i dont know its right or not...i read it somewhere so i tried

Comment: So , is it creating file now ?

Comment: From day 1 when i did this..in any phone it created the linguist directory but when i click the capture button..i hear the capture sound but image isnt stored..!! Also , for phones with SD card it stores the image properly in linguist dir ..!!

Comment: I didnt get any reply from you... !! :(

Comment: Ah there you are, I was waiting for you yesterday in office time. Now I will be back on Monday morning.

Comment: Im here only ...i was waiting for your reply since 2days .!

Comment: Opps... anyways, I am busy in office today.

Comment: I have edited your question so it will be back in current question's queue. I hope someone else will see it and answer to you.